# pdfcomment with reserved characters

Tags: verbatim, pdfcomment

I would like to include reserved characters such as `_` within comments so that I can include file links in comments.

If I try to enclose a sentence in a `verbatim` environment within a pdfcomment environment, such as this

```
\pdfcomment{\begin{verbatim}F:\images_test\20140105\DSC_0175.JPG\end{verbatim}}
```

I get an error saying that the reserved character can't be used in a pdf comment.

How can I do this? I would prefer not to escape individual reserved characters one at a time (e.g. `\_`) as it makes the comments hard to read in the latex code itself, although I know this can work.

Here is a MWE that does not compile in latex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
test\pdfcomment{\begin{verbatim}C:\User_test\end{verbatim}}

test\pdfcomment{C:\User_test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The underscore is no problem. Take the verbatim environment away and that works fine. So if you used \backslash for \, I guess it would work. Although this doesn't show a pop-up in my viewer (but neither does the documentation). If you switch to GNU/Linux, your paths wouldn't have this problem!

Comment: You need to indent code by **4** spaces. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @cfr -- The underscores will also be a problem.  `pdfcomment` relies on `\pdfstringdef` from `hyperref`.

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @jon OK. It worked fine for me when I tested it but maybe it causes other issues later on. (That is, when I just removed the verbatim environment and changed to unix-style paths, I got no errors and I got a pop-up as expected.)

Comment: @cfr -- Did the popup contain the underscore?  Most pdf viewers I have won't show the content of the popup at all (`evince` and `zathura`; `mupdf` does not indicate any annotation whatsoever), but with `acroread` only an escaped underscore will show up.

Comment: Sumatra pdf shows the comments. Only an escaped underscore will appear in the popup.

Comment: I've added the MWE.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't plan to use `\pdfcomment` as argument to another command, this will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\PDFcomment}{%
  \begingroup
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\\ 
    \lowercase{\endgroup\let~\textbackslash}%
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode`\{=1 \catcode`\}=2 \catcode`\\=\active
  \PDF@comment}
\def\PDF@comment#1{\pdfcomment{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tracingmacros=1
test\PDFcomment{C:\User_test}
\tracingmacros=0

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg. When I run this the code compiles without errors, which is progress, but the \ characters disappear in the comment. Do you find this?

Comment: @Chogg Here's a fixed version.

Comment: I run into difficulties if I try to use options. I assume that I need to change the line
    \def\PDF@comment#1{\pdfcomment{#1}\endgroup}
to something like
    \def\PDF@comment#1#2{\pdfcomment[#1]{#2}\endgroup}

but I don't really know how to write this code. Is this correct?

Comment: @Chogg Please, add an example with options.